# micronaut declarative client fail to parse json response

Tags: micronaut

I'm using a declarative http client for testing APIs.

The interface clarification is as below.

```java
@Client("/iceberg/v1")
public interface TestClient {
    @Get("/namespaces")
    HttpResponse<String> listNamespaces();

    @Post(value = "/namespaces")
    HttpResponse<String> createNamespace(@Body String body);
}
```

test code

```java
HttpResponse<String> res = testClient.createNamespace(reqBody);
```

When I give the payload that return 200, it can get the response properly.
But when I'm testing the case return 400, the response body is:

```json
{
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "/iceberg/v1/namespaces?catalog_id=1",
                "templated": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Invalid JSON: Cannot parse string array from non-array: \"big\" (through reference chain: org.apache.iceberg.rest.requests.CreateNamespaceRequest[\"namespace\"])"
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "Invalid JSON"
}
```

I can get it normally from other http clients, but the micronaut client gives me following error

```
Invalid JSON
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Invalid JSON
    at app//io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.makeErrorFromRequestBody(DefaultHttpClient.java:2238)
    at app//io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.forwardResponseToPromise(DefaultHttpClient.java:2189)
    at app//io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.channelReadInstrumented(DefaultHttpClient.java:2158)
    at app//io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$FullHttpResponseHandler.channelReadInstrumented(DefaultHttpClient.java:2126)
    at app//io.micronaut.http.client.netty.SimpleChannelInboundHandlerInstrumented.channelRead0(SimpleChannelInboundHandlerInstrumented.java:46)
    at app//io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
```

I don't know how to troubleshooting this, much appreciate for any help.

I have checked the response json resposne is valid
I wonder if there is any format of response defined that can handle this problem

Comment: The `@Client` annotation has a property [`errorType`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/client/annotation/Client.html#errorType()) where you can set the class of the bean representing the error.